# spring-integration-kafka EAP Icons not showing in Spring STS integration-graph tab

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka, spring-tool-suite

I'm currently using Spring Tool Suite (Version: 3.6.3.CI-B2266066, Build Id: 201411050946, Platform: Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.1)) with Spring Integration 4.0.3.

I've imported spring-integration-kafka branch 1.1.0 into a my project and am using both the int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter and int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter within a Spring configuration XML file.  When I go into the integration-graph tab view however I'm not seeing an icon for either of those.  Is there any way to get that to show in this graph?  I see the spring-integration-kafka jar file contains some-sort of icon in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no support for the extension projects in the graph.

You could open a [JIRA 'Improvement' Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/IDE).

Comment: Ok good to know. I've created this JIRA for that: https://jira.spring.io/browse/IDE-1360 . Thanks Gary.